# JSartoolkit : camera_para.dat for Android rear cam

Tags: javascript, android, artoolkit, jsartoolkit

I have (again) a trouble using JSartoolkit 5 (https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5).

I'm trying to use the rear cam of my device (Android - Nexus 5x, if that matters). I've seen that this framework uses `.dat` files in order to import cam settings.

So, I used `.dat` files that are provided in the repo (there : https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5/tree/master/examples/Data).

But both of those files uses the user (facing) cam on my Android device.

Does someone have a file I can use to stream the rear cam on Android? Or knows how to set it up?

**EDIT:**

*I used this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artoolworks.ar.utils.calib_camera as said in artoolkit documentation. However, when I finish the calibration process, it says it upload the data: I don't know where, and how I can use it. **Can someone tell me how I can export a .dat file from this app?***

Comment: Well.. I've ended up with a solution that I'll post soon. That doesn't come from .dat files, but from the JSartoolkit API using getUserMedia() which is bugging in Chrome Android.

Comment: Hey man! Any updates on the status of this question?

Answer (score 2):

all you need is use right device of your phone/tablet. It nothing to do with camera_para.dat. You need to use  `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, it will return you enum of devices on your phone.